# How can I make a parallel for-loop calling a function that returns 2 parameters?

Tags: go

I want to fetch data in parallels. So for example, I have an array of `UserID` (string), and I want to fetch all the users of the array in parallel, and finally have an array of `Users`:

```
func getUser(userIDs []string) {
    var users []User
    var user User

    // We create a waitgroup - basically block until N tasks say they are done
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    // We add 1 to the wait group - each worker will decrease it back
    wg.Add(len(userIDs))
    for id := range userIDs {
        user, err = h.Repository.GetUserByID(id)
        // Here is the problem. I should do a 
        go h.Repository.GetUserByID(id)
        // to be parallel, but then I can not receive the user result
        users = append(users, user)
        wg.Done()
    }
    // Now we wait for everyone to finish - again, not a must.
    // You can just receive from the channel N times, and use a timeout or something for safety
    wg.Wait()
}
```

How can I call the function that gives me the users in parallel, and at the same time saving the value in the array?

Should the `var user User` be inside the loop? Can I have race conditions if it is outside?

Comment: Don't run `h.Repository.GetUserByID()` as a goroutine, instead run another function (possibly anonymous) that calls `h.Repository.GetUserByID()` and handles its return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you have no control over `Repository.GetUserByID`, and there is no way to pass the channel directly to it, I would do something like:

```
func getUser(userIDs []string) {
    var users []User
    ch := make(chan User)
    for id := range userIDs {
        go func(ch chan User, id string){
            user, err := h.Repository.GetUserByID(id)
            if err != nil {
                println(err)
                return
            }
            ch <- user
        }(ch, id)
    }
    for range userIDs {
        users = append(users, <-ch)
    }
}
```

Writing to a slice from a goroutine might cause concurrency issues. So it is not recommended. Golang has channels exactly for this.

Comment: That worked as a charm, thanks!